# remove specific text from variable - jquery

Tags: javascript

I have a variable in my script containing data `test/test1`. The part `test/` is already stored in another variable. I want to remove `test/` from the previous variable and want to store remaining part in another variable. how can I do this??

Thanks in advance...`:)`

blasteralfred

Comment: Does the data always have at most one '/'? is '/' always the end of the already stored variable? There are a lot of ways. String methods, regular expressions..

Comment: Do so you just want to split the string at the /?

Comment: i want to remove the specific text, which will be always at the beginning part of the variable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your case, `x/y`:

`var success = myString.split('/')[1]`

You split the string by /, giving you `['x', 'y']`. Then, you only need to target the second element (zero-indexed of course.)

Edit: For a more general case, "notWantedwanted":

```
var success = myString.replace(notWantedString, '');
```

Where notWantedString is equal to what you want to get rid of; in this particular case, "notWanted".

Comment: hi @Zirak, i want to remove the specific text, which will be always at the beginning part of the variable, not just by splitting it

Comment: If it'll be in the form of "toRemove/wanted", this will work. However, I'll add another possibility in my answer.

Comment: i used myString.split('test/')[1]

Answer (score 2):

If your requirement is as straightforward as it sounds from your description, then this will do it:

```
var a = "test/test1";
var result = a.split("/")[1];
```

If your prefix is always the same (test/) and you want to just strip that, then:

```
 var result = a.substring(5);
```

And if your prefix varies but is always terminated with a /, then:

```
var result = a.substring(a.indexOf("/") + 1);
```

Comment: var result = myString.split("/")[1];

Comment: @blasteralfred: that'll be fine as long as the 2nd portion never contains another /.

Answer (score 1):

To split at the first occurence of "/":

```
var oldstring = "test/test1";
var newstring = oldstring.substring(oldstring.indexOf("/")+1);
```

There are many other ways to do this, the other answers work fine too.

Answer (score 0):

Have your pick:

[JavaScript replace() function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp).

```
var data = "test/test1";
data = data.replace(/data/gi, 'test/');
```

Or:

```
var data = "test/test1";
var dataArray = data.split('/');
var data1 = dataArray[0];
var data2 = dataArray[1];
```